# jQuery zClip delegate need to click twice

Tags: jquery, events, zclip

I want to enable zClip for ajax loaded results (json data, turned into html snippet)... But there's a problem because the zClip attaches the `click` event by itself...

```
    $('ul.detail_list').delegate("a.clipboard", "click", function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).zclip({
                            path:'images/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                            copy:$(this).text(),
                            afterCopy:function(){
                                window.open('....');
                            },
                            clickAfter: false
                        });
```

I have to click twice for Zclip to fire. Otherwise this code is working as it should (if i do `alert` or `console.log` instead of zClip it fires each and every time)...

So how can I attach Zclip to prevent this?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention `ul.detail_list` is the html snippet that's generated after json response.

html snippet (dynamically generated from json response):

```
    <ul class="detail_list">
    <li><a href="#" class="clipboard">text to copy 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="clipboard">text to copy 2</a></li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will help, I would try like this:

```
$("body").undelegate('ul.detail_list', "click",  function(eventUndelegated) {
    $('ul.detail_list').delegate("a.clipboard", "click", function(eventDelegated){
        eventDelegated.preventDefault();
        eventDelegated.stopPropagation();
        $(this).zclip({
            path:'images/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:$(this).text(),
            afterCopy:function(){
                window.open('....');
            },
            clickAfter: false
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention ul.detail_list is the html snippet that's generated after json response...so no go with this code...

Comment: so you want to first stop clicking function on `ul.detail_list` with the undelegate and then setup another clicking on `a.clipboard` elements with delegate. could you improve the question with some HTML so that it become clearer what are you trying to do ?